# synchronized counter in clojure

Tags: multithreading, clojure, volatile

If I want to keep a global counter (e.g. to count number of incoming requests across multiple threads), then the best way to do in java would be to use a volatile int. Assuming, clojure is being used is there a better (better throughput) way to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would do this with an [atom](http://clojure.org/atoms) in Clojure:

```
(def counter (atom 0N))

;; increment the counter
(swap! counter inc)

;; read the counter
@counter
=> 1
```

This is totally thread-safe, and surprisingly high performance. Also, since it uses Clojure's abitrary-precision numeric handling, it isn't vulnerable to integer overflows in the way that a volatile int can be.....

Comment: would it provide better throughput then using a volatile int? if yes, any insights on why/how is it better.

Comment: An atom would be a bit slower than a volatile int. But unless you are counting millions of events per second, the difference wouldn't be big enough to notice. And at that level of throughput, a volatile int would overflow in less than an hour anyway......

Comment: On Clojure 1.3, it can overflow: `(swap! (atom 9223372036854775807) inc)` throws an overflow exception. The fix is to use BigInts: `(swap! (atom 9223372036854775807N) inc)` or the auto-promoting `inc'` function

Comment: Good point Justin (I'm still on 1.2). Guess the fix is to initialize the counter with a BigInt..... amending it now

Answer (score 7):

Define a global counter as an [`agent`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/agent)

```
(def counter (agent 0))
```

To increase the value contained in the agent you [`send`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/send) a function (in this case [`inc`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/inc)) to the agent:

```
(send counter inc)
```

To read the current value you can use [`deref`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/deref) or the `@` reader macro:

```
@counter ;; same as (deref counter)
```

Agents are only one of several available reference types. You can read more about these things on the Clojure website:

- [High-level overview](http://clojure.org/state)
- [Software transactional memory with refs](http://clojure.org/refs)
- [Asynchronous agents](http://clojure.org/agents)
- [Atoms](http://clojure.org/atoms)